# node.js merging two json documents using request

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, request

I'm having trouble getting two JSON APIs on a website to merge into a single array rather than two.

My two JSON strings look like this:

```
{
    "users": [
        { 
             "name": "test1",
             "uniqueid": "randomlygeneratedUUID"
        },
        { 
             "name": "test2",
             "uniqueid": "randomlygeneratedUUID"
        },
        { 
             "name": "test3",
             "uniqueid": "randomlygeneratedUUID"
        }
}

{
    "users": [
        { 
             "name": "test4",
             "uniqueid": "randomlygeneratedUUID"
        },
        { 
             "name": "test5",
             "uniqueid": "randomlygeneratedUUID"
        },
        { 
             "name": "test6",
             "uniqueid": "randomlygeneratedUUID"
        }
}
```

and using something like Request, I grab the two URLs (the code looks like this):

```
var RequestMultiple = function (urls, callback) {
    'use strict';
    var results = {}, t = urls.length, c = 0,
        handler = function (error, response, body) {
            var url = response.request.uri.href;
            results[url] = { error: error, response: response, body: body };
            if (++c === urls.length) { callback(results); }
        };
    while (t--) { request(urls[t], handler); }
};
var DoRequest = function() {
    var urls = ["url1", "url2"];
    RequestMultiple(urls, function(responses) {
        for (url in responses) {
            response = responses[url];
            if (response.body){
                var JsonBody1 = JSON.parse(response[urls[0]]);
                var JsonBody2 = JSON.parse(response[urls[1]]);
        var MergeJsonBody = JsonBody1.concat(JsonBody2);
        console.log(JSON.stringify(MergeJsonBody).toString());
            } else {
                console.log('Url', url, response.error);
            }
         }
     });
});
console.log(DoRequest());
```

The issue I'm having is it doesn't merge, but when it does it looks like this:
`{"users": [{ "name": "test1","uniqueid": "randomlygeneratedUUID"},{ "name": "test2","uniqueid": "randomlygeneratedUUID"},{ "name": "test3","uniqueid": "randomlygeneratedUUID"}} unidentified {"users": [{ "name": "test4","uniqueid": "randomlygeneratedUUID"},{ "name": "test5","uniqueid": "randomlygeneratedUUID"},{ "name": "test6","uniqueid": "randomlygeneratedUUID"}}`

And it returns an error about the string unidentified.
When I don't get that error, it only shows the second JSON body.

What am I doing wrong? And is there a module or a best in practice way to do this?

EDIT:

Okay I took the solution provided, and I still hit a wall. To counter the issues I basically just had two unique requests that add to a local array variable, then once the command was triggered, create the array, then erase all the items from the array and start all over again. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all both of your JSONs are missing closing square brackets. I guess its typo but below is the correct JSON.

```
{
    "users": [
        {
            "name": "test4",
            "uniqueid": "randomlygeneratedUUID"
        },
        {
            "name": "test5",
            "uniqueid": "randomlygeneratedUUID"
        },
        {
            "name": "test6",
            "uniqueid": "randomlygeneratedUUID"
        }
    ]
}
```

Now change below line of code

```
JsonBody1.concat(JsonBody2);
```

to

```
JsonBody1.users.concat(JsonBody2.users);
```

This will should give you expected results. You are doing concat  on the actual objects instead of arrays.